# Wald test vs Chi-Square test for logistic regression models

Tags: binary, logistic-regression

Could anybody let me know the difference between Wald test and Chi-square test in logistic regression?
I want to compare the effect of two treatments over a binomial variable (0=fail, 1=success). 
I've been running logistic regression (glm) and I cannot make the decision between using Wald test and Chi-square. The p-value is slightly different.

Thanks